# MvvmCross and Xamarin Forms, Android app crashes with null reference error when getting accent color

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I've created a simple Xamarin Forms app with MvvmCross to try and figure out an error I'm having on another project. This simple app is available here: https://github.com/selaromdotnet/XamFormsAppTest

It has a single page with a toolbar item that has an icon on it.

If you look at the commit history, this project loads just fine and the icon does too.

But in the most recent commit, I followed this guide here (https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) and this post here ([Xamarin.Forms null reference exception when applying Material Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082135/xamarin-forms-null-reference-exception-when-applying-material-theme)) to update the project to use MvvmCross with Material design.

Now on the android app, the OnCreate method for the MvxFormsAppCompatActivity it crashes with this error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.GetAccentColor () [0x00006] inC:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:159
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetupInit (Android.Content.Context activity, System.Reflection.Assembly resourceAssembly) [0x0000c] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:118
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (Android.Content.Context activity, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Forms.cs:72
   at MvvmCross.Forms.Droid.MvxFormsAndroidSetup.CreateViewPresenter () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-Forms\MvvmCross.Forms.Droid\MvxFormsAndroidSetup.cs:55
   at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetup.CreateViewDispatcher () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Platform\MvxAndroidSetup.cs:124
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeViewDispatcher () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:260 
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x000f8] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:91 
   at MvvmCross.Core.Platform.MvxSetup.Initialize () [0x00006] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Platform\MvxSetup.cs:37 
   at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureInitialized () [0x0004e] in  C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Platform\MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.cs:45
   at MvvmCross.Forms.Droid.MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00013] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-Forms\MvvmCross.Forms.Droid\MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.cs:64
   at XamFormsAppTest.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00017] in D:\VisualStudio\OSS\XamFormsAppTest\XamFormsAppTest\XamFormsAppTest.Android\MainActivity.cs:21
   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in 8b5e0f4c6f594871ab0afcbcb2317289>:0  
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:6ce77b2f-ee95-4ad0-bd89-6baa2e4d7b05> (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

I'm guessing it's not finding the color correctly in the resources but I am at a loss for how to troubleshoot this problem. I tried changing the filename to color.xml and tried defining the accentColor as a color instead of a reference to @color/accent...

I'm really stuck here and have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my project?

Answer (score 2):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

First, please make sure you have read the [Official tutorial](https://medium.com/@martijn00/using-mvvmcross-with-xamarin-forms-part-1-eaee5815bb8c)  to create a `MvvmCross` project with `Xamarin.Forms`. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/martijn00/MvxForms) about how to create a `MvvmCross Forms` project. Please modify your `MainPage.xaml` code according to the document.

We could find that the `NullReferenceException` has an order :

```
MainActivity.OnCreate --> MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate --> .. --> Init --> SetupInit --> GetAccentColor
```

It was null when the system call `MainActivity.OnCreate` method, so we can infer that not finding the color correctly in the resources because your `MainActivity` hasn't been initialized. We should call `MainActivity`'s  `OnCreate` method after it was prepared. It seems **we must  add a `SplashScreen` to initialize some resource.**

Here is my code :

```
[Activity(
   Label = "MvxForms"
   , MainLauncher = true
   , Icon = "@drawable/icon"
   , NoHistory = true
   , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreen()
        : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }

    protected override void TriggerFirstNavigate()
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        base.TriggerFirstNavigate();
    }
}
```

Then, your `NullReferenceException` will be gone, but after doing this, its still have a `Exception` :

```
 FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException:
 Problem seen creating View-ViewModel lookup table 
 - you have more than one View registered for the ViewModels: 2*MainViewModel (MainActivity,MainPage) 
 ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

> If your ViewModel is called MainViewModel and your Forms page is too, you might get a name conflict because MvvmCross will have 2 view to viewmodel lookups. You can prevent this by naming your Activity differently like "FormsActivity.cs".

You could also rename your `MainViewModel` to `MvxMainViewModel`(whatever you like), then this exception will disappear.